# Epoxy : how to use the @AutoModel annotation and handle clicks without controller?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, epoxy, epoxy-modelview

I am starting to use the epoxy library because I am looking for a library to write less code while using the `RecyclerView` component.

The `EpoxyRecyclerView` seems to be a great component since you can simply give the models (basically a simple list), thanks to the `setModels` method.

### Question 1

The first question is : it is possible to automatically set an id to a model (using the `@AutoModel` ?) without using a controller ?

For example, I have the following `DataBindingEpoxyModel` class :

```
@EpoxyModelClass(layout = R.layout.item_header)
abstract class HeaderModel
  : DataBindingEpoxyModel()
{

  @StringRes
  @EpoxyAttribute
  var title: Int? = null

}
```

And I use it like this in my `Fragment` :

```
val models = mutableListOf<EpoxyModel<*>>()
models.add(HeaderModel_().title(R.string.catalogue_header_categories_title)
//  [...]
 recyclerView?.setModels(models)
```

This code crashes because I do not set an `id` to the `HeaderModel_()` instance. The `AutoModel` annotation have to be used on a field only, so is there a way to automatically set an id to my model instance with no controller ?

### Question 2

The second question is : it is possible to handle a click without using a controller ?

Using the code of the question 1, how to handle a click on several widget of the layout (in my case, a click on the `TextView` or a click on the `itemView`) ? Is there a way to override the holder used by the `DataBindingEpoxyModel` in order to handle the click directly into the holder ?

In my case I do not want to define the `OnClickListener` as an attribute of my `HeaderModel` because I would like to define the same behavior for all models of the type `HeaderModel` (without using a controller).

Thank you in advance for you help !

**Edit :** I found the answer of the question 2. I just need to override one of the `bind` method of the `DataBindingEpoxyModel`. But I do not find a way to automatically set an id to a model without a controller and the `@AutoModel` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer from the github repo for the first question :

> There is no way to automatically set an id (besides automodel, which I
>   wouldn't recommend these days anyway) - you should always set an id
>   manually on each model. It is best to do this by setting a human
>   readable string. This is detailed more in the wiki